# Good design for a reusable class with many derived classes

Tags: c++, oop, design-patterns, polymorphism

I have a class that will serve as the base class for (many) other classes. The derived classes each have a slight variation in their logic around a single function, which itself will be one of a set group of external functions. I aim to have something which is efficient, clear and will result in the minimal amount of additional code per new deriving class:

Here is what I have come up with:

```
// ctor omitted for brevity

class Base
{
public:
    void process(batch_t &batch)
    {
        if (previous) previous->process(batch);
        pre_process(batch);
        proc.process(batch);
        post_process(batch);
    }

protected:
    // no op unless overridden
    virtual void pre_process(batch_t &batch) {}
    virtual void post_process(batch_t &batch) {}

    Processor proc;
    Base* previous;
}
```

- Expose the 'process' function which follows a set pattern
- The core logic of the function is defined by a drop in class 'Processor'
- Allow modification of this pattern via two virtual functions, which define additional work done before/after the call to Processor::proc
- Sometimes, this object has a handle to another which must do something else before it, for this I have a pointer 'previous'

Does this design seem good or are there some glaring holes I haven't accounted for? Or are there other common patterns used in situations like this?

Comment: Why CRTP, if you don't use `DERIVED` anywhere?

Comment: I will do in other places, I just posted a minimal example of my class pertinent to the question of extending the process function

Comment: You should either remove CRTP then, or modify the example to show us how it is used. I don't think that we can add anything useful to this question though.

Comment: Each `Base<Foo>` is a distinct class. You can't bind `Base<Foo1>` and `Base<Foo2>` to the same reference or pointer. So what purpose is the CRTP really serving? I think geza is right.

Comment: Ah I see, in which case I can scrap CRTP and just use the vtable. I expect actually that the Processor::proc call will dominate the additional overhead anyway. Ignoring the CRTP part, does the rest of the design seem sensible?

Comment: You can do it this way. But I would wrap every step in private methods, which would call the protected virtual void's so that I in future can add additional base logic to every step.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Does this design seem good or are there some glaring holes I haven't accounted for? Or are there other common patterns used in situations like this?

Without knowing more about your goals, all I can say is that it seems quite sensible. It's so sensible, in fact, there's a common name for this idiom: A ["Non-virtual Interface"](https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/More_C%2B%2B_Idioms/Non-Virtual_Interface). Also described as a ["Template Method Design Pattern"](http://www.blackwasp.co.uk/TemplateMethod.aspx) by the gang of four, if you are in Java-sphere.

Answer (score 0):

You are currently using the so called "Template Method" pattern (see, for instance, [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/template_method/cpp/1)). You have to note that it uses inheritance to essentially modify the behaviour of the `process(batch)` function by overriding the `pre_process` and `post_process` methods. This creates strong coupling. For instance, if you subclass your base class to use a particular `pre_process` implementation, then you can't use this implementation in any other subclass without duplicating code.

I personally would go with the "Strategy" pattern (see, for instance, [here](https://sourcemaking.com/design_patterns/strategy)) which is more flexible and allows code re-use more easily, as follows:

```
struct PreProcessor {
    virtual void process(batch&) = 0;
};

struct PostProcessor {
    virtual void process(batch&) = 0;
};

class Base {

public:
    //ctor taking pointers to subclasses of PreProcessor and PostProcessor

    void process(batch_t &batch)
    {
        if (previous) previous->process(batch);
        pre_proc->process(batch);
        proc.process(batch);
        post_proc->process(batch);
    }

private:

    PreProcessor* pre_proc;
    Processor proc;
    PostProcessor* post_proc;
    Base* previous;
}
```

Now, you can create subclasses of `PreProcessor` and `PostProcessor` which you can mix and match and then pass to your `Base` class. You can of course apply the same approach for your `Processor` class.

Answer (score 0):

Given your information, I don't see any benefit of using Inheritance (one Base and many Derived classes) here. Writing a new (whole) class just because you have a new couple of pre/post process logic is not a good idea. Not to mention, this will make difficult to reuse these logic.

I recommend a more composable design:

```
typedef void (*Handle)(batch_t&);

class Foo
{
public:
    Foo(Handle pre, Handle post, Foo* previous) :
        m_pre(pre),
        m_post(post),
        m_previous(previous) {}

    void process(batch_t& batch)
    {
        if (m_previous) m_previous->process(batch);
        (*m_pre)(batch);
        m_proc.process(batch);
        (*m_post)(batch);
    }

private:
    Processor m_proc;
    Handle m_pre;
    Handle m_post;
    Foo* m_previous;
}
```

This way, you can create any customized Foo object with any logic of pre/post process you want. If the creation is repetitive, you can always extract it into a `createXXX` method of a `FooFactory` class.

P/S: if you don't like function pointers, you can use whatever representing a function, such as interface with one method, or lambda expression ...